# Why the database dump is not getting imported in following scenario?

Tags: php, mysql, linux, database, terminal

I've one `'xyz.sql'` dump file uploaded in `'test'` folder on the server.

Created a blank database called 'dummy' in MySQL database using PHPMyAdmin.

Then I logged into the server using ssh and run the following command, it gave me no error but the database is not getting imported.

```
mysqldump -uroot -pxyz123 new_db > xyz.sql
```

The username I use to login to the **PHPMyAdmin** is **root** and password is **xyz123**. The blank database I created is `'new_db'`, the  file which I want to import is `xyz.sql`.

You can see in above command I've used these details.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `<` instead of `>` when you import the dump. First check if `xyz.sql` still contains your dump!